# IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Remove("userClient") removing all objects

Tags: c#, caching, windows-phone-8, isolatedstorage

In IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings I have 5 strings, and after logout I want to remove only "userClient", but it clears all the strings instead.

```
private static void ClearAllAndGoToSignIn()
    {
        App.MainViewModel.UserDetails = new UserItem();
        App.MainViewModel.ReceiversList.Clear();
        App.MainViewModel.TimelineList.Clear();
        if (IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Contains("userClient"))
        { IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Remove("userClient"); }
        IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Save();
        Storage.ClearStorage();

        Application.Current.Terminate();

    }
```

Comment: What is that `Storage` object? What is the `ClearStorage` method supposed to do?

Comment: are you sure that you're giving the correct `key` value to remove? I mean are you having the same `key` value for all the items you store?